# "Non strictly positive occurrence of ..."

Tags: coq

I try to define the following type

```
Inductive t : Type -> Type :=
  | I : t nat
  | F : forall A, (t nat -> t A) -> t A.
```

and I get the following error:

```
Non strictly positive occurrence of "t" in "forall A : Type, (t nat -> t A) -> t A".
```

- What does this error mean?
- Is there a way to "fix" the definition to make it valid?
- Where can I learn more about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look up common error messages in the Coq reference manual: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html?highlight=positive#coq:exn.non-strictly-positive-occurrence-of-ident-in-type

Essentially, if a constructor contains functions (such as `t nat -> t A`), they cannot mention the inductive type being defined as part of an argument (`t nat`).

```
        vvvvvvvvvvvvvv argument
F : ... (t nat -> t A)               -> t A
                  ^ OK ("positive occurence")
         ^ Not OK ("negative occurence")
```

This section in Certified Programming with Dependent Types (CPDT) explains the problem with a simplified example: http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.InductiveTypes.html#lab30

If you could define the type

```
Inductive term : Set :=
| App : term -> term -> term
| Abs : (term -> term) -> term.
```

then you could define the function

```
Definition uhoh (t : term) : term :=
  match t with
    | Abs f => f t
    | _ => t
  end.
```

and `uhoh (Abs uhoh)` would diverge.